# In Python, how might one replace a word within a string with a random item from a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a certain character formation `_n_` and replace it with a random string from an array.

In wordlibrary.py:

```
    import random

    nouns =   ['wombat','zebra','elephant','lamp','desk','computer','python','castle','king','scribble','doodle','motorcycle','car','train','plane']

    def chooseNoun():
        randomNoun = random.randint(0,len(nouns))
        nounChoice = nouns[randomNoun-1]
        return nounChoice
```

Now, in storyCreator.py:

```
    import wordLibrary

    originalString = input("Type a sentence or story. Use \'_n_\' to denote a noun, \'_adj_\' to denote an adjective, \'_v_\' to denote a verb, \'_adv_\' to denote an adverb, or \'_l_\' to denote a location.     Type Here: ")

    nounCheck = '_n_'
```

How can I find `_n_` in the string and replace it with a random word from the list each time?

Comment: use `random.choice` to _randomly_ select a word from your list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str.replace` and `random.choice` together, and remember to assign the new string:

```
while '_n_' in oldString:
    oldString = oldString.replace('_n_', random.choice(nouns))
```

Comment: Is there a way for it to randomize for each instance?

Comment: @RaskorProgramming Do you understand the loop?

Answer (score 2):

[`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) has an argument to limit the number of replacements.

Loop through the number of occurrences of your string in the string being modified, and replace 1 occurrence each loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this in multiple ways and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a new random choice for each occurrence of _n_
You could split the sentence by spaces (for a more crafty solution you may want to use re.findall instead), and then either append the original word or a random one if the word is _n_.

```
newString = []

for n in originalString.split():                                                                │
    newString.append(n=='_n_' and random.choice(nouns) or n)

' '.join(newString)
```

Example:

"My _n_ is really tall, but not as strong as my _n_."

Output:

"My **lamp** is really tall, but not as strong as my **wombat**."

Answer (score 0):

If you could make the character to insert a word `{n}` instead of `_n_` you could just use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
originalString.format(n=random.choice(nouns), v=random.choice(verbs), adj=random.choice(adjectives), adv=random.choice(adverbs), l=random.choice(locations))
```

Comment: Ah you're right. My code would use the same word for all of them.

Comment: Well I meant the formatting of your code block, but okay.

Comment: What's wrong with my code block? I know I violated PEP by going over 80 characters per line, but it is still a one-liner.

Comment: PEP, SHMEP. I never cared much for that. I talking about the appearance, use a code block not an inline block.